# Overlaying two/more graphs using R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been referring stackoverflow posts and came up with query over a gglot2 features.

The data set used for code is as follows.

```
TimeStamp   data_1      data_2      data_3      
15:11:37.474    99.791028   0.312498    99.47853    
15:16:22.373    99.791028   0.729162    99.061866   
15:21:37.424    99.791028   0.104166    99.686862   
15:31:52.475    88.02027            90.520254   
15:42:07.157    99.99936    0.208332    99.791028   
15:43:22.279    99.99936    0.52083     99.47853    
15:45:37.673    99.686862   0       99.686862   
15:52:52.872    99.686862   0.729162    98.9577 

p1<- ggplot(df, aes(TimeStamp, data_1,group=1)) + geom_point() + geom_point(data = df[df$data_1 > 80,], pch = 21, fill = NA, size = 4, colour = "red", stroke = 1) + geom_line()
p2<-ggplot(df, aes(TimeStamp, data_3,group=1)) + geom_point() + geom_point(data = df[df$data_3 > 70,], pch = 21, fill = NA, size = 4, colour = "blue", stroke = 1) + geom_line()
```

I am trying to overlay P1 and P2 into same X and Y axis using `print(p1+p2).`
But, came up with below error.

```
Error in p + o : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("+.gg", "Ops.data.frame") for "+"
```

what these graphs will do is; it will circle certain data points based on conditions and display two graphs in same region.

Comment: You can't add plots like that. You can add layers if you like. Just have one `ggplot()` call but don't pass a data.frame or aes() in that function. Specify the correct data and aes() on each geom_* directly. Or even better, properly reshape your data to a [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) format then use aesthetics to properly color and stack the layers.

Comment: dput(p1<- ggplot(df, aes(TimeStamp, data_1,group=1)) + geom_point() + geom_point(data = df[df$data_1 > 90,], pch = 21, fill = NA, size = 4, colour = "red", stroke = 1)
p2<- p1+ geom_point(data = df[df$data_3 > 99.2,], pch = 21, fill = NA, size = 4, colour = "blue", stroke = 1))
> print(p2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
p1<- ggplot(df, aes(TimeStamp, data_1,group=1)) + geom_point(pch = 21, fill = NA, size = 4, colour = "red", stroke = 1)+geom_point()+geom_line(colour = "red")
p2 <- p1+geom_line(data=df, aes(TimeStamp, data_3),colour="blue")+
  geom_point(data=df, aes(TimeStamp, data_3,group=data_3),colour="blue",pch = 21, size = 4, stroke = 1,fill= NA)+geom_point(data=df, aes(TimeStamp, data_3,group=data_3))


print(p2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Arun. This solution is what I expected.Quick question, how do you make blue data points exactly same like red points ?

Comment: @user6750230 Have assigned geom_point(data=df, aes(TimeStamp, data_3,group=1), Please vote up if you like answer...

Comment: Hi Arun, not sure u got me.Data_1 points are black & it is circled in the graph.But,points in data_3 are only circled and black data point is missing.I m not sure how to get it.Appreciate ur help in this regard.

Comment: @user6750230 Please find the updated code and solution to your query